# Hide pivots in only one model result

Tags: php, laravel

I know how to hide pivots from model results but i have to hide pivots in just one model result not all of them because i using model pivots in another places of my code. 
with this code `Laravel` hide pivots from results :

```
    protected $hidden = array('pivot');
```

i just need to hide from :

```
    $post = Post::find(1)->comments()->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`setHidden`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L2122-L2131) on every model in the relation:

```php
$post = Post::find(1);

$post->comments->each(function ($comment) {
    $comment->setHidden(['pivot']);
});
```